# How to completely manage heap memory allocation of std containers like map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, heap-memory, std, memory-pool

I'm interested in using multiple std map<int,int> and I want all of them to allocate the elements from a common memory pool. From what I've read so far, I can use custom allocators such as the Boost pool_alloc to achieve this.

My question is, despite using something like Boost pool_alloc to manage the allocation of the elements themselves, will std map still use little bits of heap memory as some form of container overhead that will NOT be managed by boost pool_alloc? I'm thinking something along the lines of pointer to elements with regards to the use std map itself?

Comment: are you asking for a container containing pointers? sorry for asking, but i don't get it so far...

Comment: @Stefan: No, not container containing pointers. Given that the custom allocator will be responsible for the allocation of the elements themselves, I'm asking if ALL the container memory overhead of std::map will be covered by the custom allocator as well. I hope this helps clarify my issue

Comment: ok. understood. no. the specific allocator is responsible for allocate space on the heap for the specific elements, not for the container itself. if you want to change that you need to overload operator new/delete for your specific container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short version**

A map type such as:

```
typedef std::map<
    int,
    int,
    less<int>,
    boost::pool_allocator<pair<const int, int> >
    > 
    AMapType;
```

Will do all the allocation it needs as it grows using boost::pool_allocators. Some of the initial structure is likely to be created on the stack. How much and what the exact structure will be though is implementation dependent.

**Allocator Rebind**

The above is possible through the use of `allocator::rebind`

All std::allocator conformant allocators (such as boost::pool_allocator) provide a rebind template struct in the form:

```
template<class U> struct rebind{
   typedef AllocatorType<U> other;
};
```

This can be used to obtain the same kind of allocator for a different type:

```
typedef AllocatorOfOther AllocatorType::rebind<ADifferentType>::other;
```

**gcc std::map internal structure**

The g++ std::map implementation (I inspected 4.7.3 and 4.1.1) is built purely out of a single node type. This includes the key value pair and the pointers and colour bit needed for the rbTree structure. To allocate this it defines a Node allocator using the rebind struct from the user provided allocator. This is used for all the allocations it does as the map grows. Each new node gets allocated in a single allocation.

**The standard**

I checked though the C++11 standard and could not find anything specifying how such structure should be allocated. Either I did not find the right part or it is not specified. Not using the user given allocator kind would seem a bit pointless though.

Comment: Just want to clarify: from what I understood, the rebind converts the element T into some sort of Node<T>, with additional left- and right- pointers (or something to that effect). Does this mean that, aside the Node elements (produced by rebind) themselves, there will be NO other allocations created by std::map?

Comment: So, I did what you did, but I used `boost::pool_allocator< int >`. And that worked. How can that work?

Comment: @JHBonarius It is likely the container implementation never actually uses the allocator for its original type and always rebinds it to some other type first. In that case probably almost any type in the template argument would work.